# Error while make in Fastjet

Tags: shared-libraries, gnu-make

```
amandeep@amandeep-Vostro-2420:~/fastjet$ make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amandeep/fastjet/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/amandeep/fastjet/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libfastjet.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libfastjet.so.0.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libfastjet.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libfastjet.so.0.0.0': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amandeep/fastjet/src'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/amandeep/fastjet/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Fastjet release : fastjet-3.2.1 (manual, doxygen, fjcore)

Ubuntu software version : 14.04

I have this problem while make. I have tried other releases also. Problem exists with every release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ make install
...
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libfastjet.so.0.0.0': Permission denied
```

A fundamental fact about Linux and unix-like operating systems is that you require root (superuser) permissions
to install software outside your home directory. Therefore run:

```
$ sudo make install
```

See [man sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)